# How to Show data from String Array ,in Single Android textview with cross image Each line contains Two Strings

Tags: android, arrays, textview

1.I am getting data from server storing inside string Array.

2.then i want to show in Android TextView ,each TextView line should Contain 2 strings(Like Skill Sets) from String array.

3.then need to add cross Image in right side of the Textview.

please help me, how to achieve this.

Comment: Share the code that you have tried

Comment: Also make your requirement a little more clear.

Comment: How many Textview you have? Is it just one or is it dynamic based on some value?

Comment: Based on String array Value its dynamic increment  SIngle Textview

Comment: Why don't you use a listview with a textview and an imageview instead?

Comment: You can find a simple tutorial for that [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html).

Comment: i want show two strings in a line, also each string should contain Cross imageview for deletion.thats why iam not used Listview.

Comment: I am still not clear with the second part of your 2nd requirement. What do you mean by 2 strings(Like Skill Sets) from String array? What data are you getting from your server?

Comment: But, having so many dynamic textview is not a good solution. Instead try to customize each row element of listview.

Comment: like skills java ,C# show from server, SO each line  example:1st line-java,C#, 2nd line -android,java script, with cross symbol right side of each String.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mystring = "This is my first sentence";
        String arr[] = mystring.split(" ", 3);

        String firstWord = arr[0];   //This
        String secondWord = arr[1];  //is
        String theRest = arr[2]; //my first sentence

        yourtextview.setText(firstWord +"  "+ secondWord);
```

and regarding for  Image in right side of the Textview put this in ur txtview'sxml.

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: splitting is not a problem , my problem is displaying two strings in Each line using dynamic data inside single Textview..!